# Cumulative probabilities

Tags: probability

Consider the cumulative probability $\mathbb{P}(X \ge 2^n)$  where

$$\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(X=2^n)= C(2^{n+1},2^n)p^{2^n}q^{2^n}$$

and $C(a,b)$ is the binomial coefficient; $p = q =0.5$ and the number of trials is $2^{n+1}$.

I get with an online calculator :

http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx

$\mathbb{P}(X \ge 2^n) = 0.69, 0.64, 0.60, 0.57, 0.55$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$; a minimum of $\mathbb{P} = 0.518$ is reached at $n = 8$ but $P = 0.537$ at $n=9$ and again  a  ¿ relative ? minimal value is reached at $n = 12$: $P= 0.513$. Shouldn't they be always decreasing values ?

Comment: Maybe you confused $P(X\geqslant2^n)$ (always decreasing) and $P(X=2^n)$ (not always decreasing).

Comment: I did not; thanks.

Comment: Then the question is odd since for every random variable $X$, the sequence $n\mapsto\mathbb P(X\geqslant2^n)$ is absolutely rigorously universally demonstrably nonincreasing.